# Can't get animation on newly created HTML elements

Tags: javascript, html, css, transition, dom-manipulation

What's up.

I'm trying to make an infinite carousel, however I'm having issues making it presentable.
The issue is essentialy that newly created "slides" don't slide smoothly (following the transition I've set) as the ones I hardcoded initially.

This is my code (PS I know it's horrible, but I'm still very much in the developmental phase lol)

HTML

```
<main class="main">
  <div id="outside-container">
    <div id="inside-container" class="cf">

      <div class="items" id="item1">
        <datalist class="data-div">
          <ul>
            <li>Some 1 </li>
            <li class="weather">wwwe</li>
            <img src="" alt=""/>
            <li>frrf</li>
          </ul>
        </datalist>
        <!-- <img src="" class="carousel-img"> -->
      </div>
      <div class="items" id="item2">
        <datalist class="data-div">
          <ul>
            <li>some2 </li>
            <li class="weather">icons</li>
            <img src="" alt=""/>
            <li>ggno73v</li>
          </ul>
        </datalist>
        <!-- <img src="" class="carousel-img"> -->
      </div>


    </div>
  </div>
  
  <div id="directions">
    <h4 id="right-button">Right</h4>
  </div>
</main>
```

CSS

```
.main {
  background-image: radial-gradient(black, rgba(48, 48, 48, 0.349));
}

#outside-container{
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  width: 400px;
  height: 60vh;
  border-radius: 5px;
  /* overflow: hidden; */
  margin: 0 auto;
}

#inside-container{
  display: flex;
  width: 1600px;
  height: 100%;
  /* overflow: hidden; */
}

.items{
  margin: 0px;
  width: 400px;
  height: 100%;
}

#item1{ background: green; }
#item2{ background: red; }
#item3{ background: blue; }
#item4{ background: yellow; }
```

and last but not least, freaking JS:

```
const dummy = 'dummy data'

const createSlide = ()=>{

  const newSlide = document.createElement('div')

  newSlide.classList = 'items'

  newSlide.style.backgroundColor = 'blue'

  newSlide.innerHTML =
  `
    <datalist class="data-div">
      <ul>
        <li><b>${dummy}</b></li>
        <li class="weather">${dummy}</li>
        <img src="" alt=""/>
        <li>${dummy}</li>
      </ul>
    </datalist>
  `

  insideContainer.append(newSlide)
}


// CONTROL

rightBtn.addEventListener('click', ()=>{

  slideAnimation()

  /* insideContainer.firstElementChild.nextElementSibling.firstElementChild.classList.remove('active')

  setTimeout(()=>{
    insideContainer.style.marginLeft = (move * -2)+'px'
    insideContainer.animate(animation, 1000)
    insideContainer.firstElementChild.nextElementSibling.firstElementChild.animate(fadeAnimation, 2000)
    insideContainer.style.marginLeft = margin_reset
  }, 100)
    
  setTimeout( ()=>{
    insideContainer.append(insideContainer.firstElementChild)
  }, 1150)
  
  setTimeout(()=>{
    insideContainer.firstElementChild.nextElementSibling.firstElementChild.classList.toggle('active')
    
  }, 1200) */
})

const slideImg = ()=> {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    resolve(
      insideContainer.style.transform = 'translateX(-400px)',
      insideContainer.style.transition = 'transform 1s'
     
    )
  })
}

const removeSlide = ()=> {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      resolve(
        insideContainer.style.marginLeft = '400px',
        insideContainer.firstElementChild.remove(),
        )
    }, 1000);
  }) 
}


const appendSlide = ()=> {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
      resolve(
        createSlide()
      )
  })
}


const toggleActive = ()=> {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    resolve(
      insideContainer.firstElementChild.firstElementChild.classList.toggle('active')
    )
  })
}

async function slideAnimation() {
  insideContainer.firstElementChild.firstElementChild.classList.remove('active')
  slideImg()
  await removeSlide()
  await appendSlide()
  await toggleActive()
}
```

Thanks in advance peeps

Comment: `rightBtn` isn't set, `let rightBtn = document.getElementById("right-button");`

Comment: No , it is set. I just forgot to copy it. That is not the issue

Comment: It could be interesting to focus on the problem, don't hesitate to edit your question to add what's missing then

Comment: thank you but I just solved it. Still, very kind of you :)